# What is "Cloud Firestore Index Write Ops"?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've an application that uses Cloud Firestore in production, at my tests my quotas was fine, but when I put my app in production at Google Play Store my quotas goes high, I see 161k API Calls and and 100k Index Write Ops, so, anyone here can explain what is Index Write Ops? I've indexes at database, but I write only one time =/

Comment: Anybody? What is Cloud Firestore Index Write Ops? Does it have any limit? It's free, cheat, expensive. Of course, can't find in any firebase documentation.